# Remove white space after detokenizing a string with apostrophe

Tags: python

I want to remove the white space in words like can't or won't either through regex or when detokenizing

```
from nltk.tokenize import WordPunctTokenizer
tok = WordPunctTokenizer()
detok = MosesDetokenizer()

pattern= "[^\w ]+ "
text= "i can ' t use this cause they won ' t fit"
string= re.sub(pattern, '', text)
tk = tok.tokenize(string)
output= detok.detokenize(tk, return_str = True)
print(output)

 "i can 't use this cause they won' t fit"
```

any ideas on how i can remove the white space after 'can' and 'won' so i can have can't and won't. When i use `output =  (' '.join(tk)).strip()` to detokenize i get double white space, one before and after the apostrophe. Example `i can ' t use this cause they won ' t fit`

Comment: It depends on what kind of input you are expecting. If the only apostrophes in the input are from contractions then you can replace `" ?' ?"` with `"'"`. However if the input involves apostrophes used as qoutes then it would be a much harder task to decide when an apostrophe should have spaces next to it or shouldn't.

Comment: You could try this pattern: `re.sub("\w\s?'\s?\w", "'", text)` - word character, optional space, literal apostrophe,optional space, word character. [Demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/t8Z5OH/2/).

Comment: @MukeshIngham it works. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

@BenT I can't say about the regex but yeah on your output you can apply the following operation:

```
output = "i can 't use this cause they won' t fit"
output = "'".join(output.split(" '"))
output = "'".join(output.split("' "))
print(output)
"i can't use this cause they won't fit"
```

One line solution is also there:

```
output = output.replace("' ", "'").replace(" '", "'")
print(output)
"i can't use this cause they won't fit"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can simple do something like:

```
output = "i can 't use this cause they won' t fit"
output = output.replace(" '", "")
print output
"i can't use this cause they won't fit"
```